# Collections.sort(list) and list.sort(Comparator...) in term of usability?

Tags: java, list, performance, sorting

I mean list.sort(..) can have a comparator that sorts the list ascending and reverseOrder

Answer (score 6):

The two methods end up executing the same code; there is zero difference between the two.

`Collections.sort` predates `list.sort`. That is because `list.sort` is a so-called [`default` interface method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html), which is a Java feature that did not exist back then. Hence why `Collections.sort` exists.

Now that default methods for interfaces is available, `list.sort` also exists, because java is OOP and 'thingYouWantToDoSomethingWith.theThingYouWantToDo' is better style.

You should use `list.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder())` for that reason. Purely style points - there is no difference in effect or performance whatsoever.

Comment: Writing `list.sort(null)` should have the same behavior as `list.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder())`. From the `List.sort` JavaDoc: `A null value indicates that the elements natural ordering should be used`